# Django queryset not escaping text in a where...in query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to construct a fairly straightforward queryset that returns a list of values based on a set of criteria in a related table. Based on values from URL params, an array of values is passed to an `in` filter on the queryset.

The problem is that Django passes those values as text **without quotes** into the SQL query and thus the query fails.

The focal table contains information on companies ("Entity") and the related table information on offices ("Office") of those companies.

This is the array of values being passed to queryset:

```
locations = [u'San Francisco', u'New York']
```

Here's the query:

```
companies = Entity.objects.values("name","summary").filter(office__city__in=locations)
```

Here's the query that actually hits SQL:

```
SELECT "entities_entity"."name", "entities_entity"."summary" FROM "entities_entity" INNER JOIN "entities_office" ON ("entities_entity"."id" = "entities_office"."entity_id") WHERE "entities_office"."city" IN (San Francisco, New York)
```

If I run the SQL query manually, but surround each of the statements in the `IN` clause with single quotes (not double quotes), it works fine.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

For what it's worth, here are the pertinent parts of the models

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=450)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

class Office(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you checking the SQL? django.db.connection.queries does not contain escaped parameters, it's just for debugging.

Comment: Ah, I was double checking the queries in PGAdmin, based on `companies.queries` -- maybe there's something wrong in my data...

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an odd behavior when Django replaces contents to apply the query filter.

Maybe it worths trying this:

> locations = [u'\'San Francisco\'', u'\'New York\'']

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's a [known](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28880) limitation of the Django queryset `query` attribute. The Django devs only provide that for debugging, and have refused to modify it to reflect the actual database backend, so it won't properly escape certain datatypes correctly.